# How do I add/append data to a js file, from html and or python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add data to my data.js file through python3. Does anyone have any ideas? The data.js file looks like this:

```
{
    "data":[
        {"Name": "Bob", "Age": "21"},
        {"Name": "Monty", "Age": "15"}
    ]
}
```

So far in python I have this:

```
import json
name = input("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
data = {
    "Name": name,
    "Age": age,
}

with open("data.js", "w") as file:
    json.dump([data], f)
```

But that saves as `[{"Name": "Bob", "Age": "23"}]`

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in the existing file and append the new data:

```
import json

with open('data.js') as f:
    content = json.load(f)

name = input("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")

person = {"name": name, "Age": age} #Build object for new person ...
content['data'].append(person) # .. and append it to your existing 'data'

with open("data.js", "w") as file:
    json.dump(content, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the entire content from scratch.

Like this:

```
import json
name = input("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
content = {'data': []} #This will be the final content of your js file

person1 = {"name": name, "Age": age} #Build objs for each person ...
content['data'].append(person1) # .. and append it to your 'data'

with open("data.js", "w") as file:
    json.dump(content, f)
```